# Implementation of parallel coordinates?

Tags: r, matlab, plot, coordinates

I want to implement parallel coordinates for my muldimensional result. Does anyone have a good link to its implementation in matlab or R? Furthermore, are there any suggestions regarding the best tool to use for producing the parallel coordinates?

Comment: No idea why this was closed, it seems reasonable to me. ggplot2 has a helper function, [`ggpcp()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/ggpcp.html) that allows you to use any data frame with the standard geoms to create a parallel coordinates plot.

Comment: You can now make interactive parallel coordinates with Plotly. Check it out: https://plot.ly/r/parallel-coordinates-plot/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**R solution**

**lattice** package comes with R and includes `parallel` function:

```
 parallel(~iris[1:4] | Species, iris)
```

[image]

**[ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_line.html)** is also your friend here:

```
D <- data.frame(Gain = rnorm(20),  
                Trader = factor(LETTERS[1:4]), 
                Day = factor(rep(1:5, each = 4)))
ggplot(D) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Trader, y = Gain, group = Day, color = Day))
```

[image]

lattice and ggplot require input data in different "shapes". For lattice it's a matrix form, each column is a variable represented on one parallel coordinate. For ggplot it's one column (Gains) and a separate indicator for the variable (Trader above). /this is the reason I used two different examples, not to mess with data reshaping here/.

If you need something quick, then lattice is probably for you. Ggplot requires some time investment.

Comment: For ggplot2 solution - there is also [ggparcoord](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/GGally/docs/ggparcoord) function in the [GGally](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/) package.

Comment: I was trying out using ggplot, it works fine for 20 items. But if I generate 40 items then each day gets 8 points(e.g. there is a vertical line in A for day1 as there are 2 points). Could you please tell me a way to split the line for every four points.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to use parallel coordinates, MATLAB has an implementation in the Statistics Toolbox: [PARALLELCOORDS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/parallelcoords.html).

Otherwise if you want to implement one yourself, the basic version (without all of the bells and whistles) should be easy to do:

```
load fisheriris            %# load some data
%#meas = zscore(meas);     %# to normalize the attributes
h = plot(meas');            %'# plot
set(gca, 'XTick',1:4, 'XTickLabel',{'SL' 'SW' 'PL' 'PW'}, 'XGrid','on')
ylabel('feature value'), title('Parallel Coordinates')

%# color according to class label
c = grp2idx(species);
clr = lines( numel(c) );
arrayfun(@(k) set(h(c==k),'Color',clr(k,:)), unique(c))
```

[image]

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain your down-vote? OP asked for either R or MATLAB code; the above code works just fine..

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because I didn't notice the question also asked for MATLAB... I feel bad and have tried to remove my downvote but its locked in.

Answer (score 6):

[GGobi](http://www.ggobi.org) has had for aeons (as its predecessor XGobi already had it).

You can access this via the [rggobi](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rggobi) package from [R](http://www.r-project.org). And being open source, you get to look under the hood too.

Answer (score 4):

The MASS package (available to most of the R installations) includes an implementation for parallel coordinates. The function `parcoord`.

From the examples of the ?parcoord -a bit corrected- for the Iris data set:

```
ir <- rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3])
parcoord(log(ir)[, c(1, 2, 3, 4)], col = 1 + (0:149)%/%50)
```