# Plotting d-dimensional data

Tags: java, r, matlab, plot, octave

I have following format of data in a .txt file.

```
नोभेम्बर 
 [0.013597779962868256, -0.10849757437254635, -0.15999846585159766, -1.2417475384869558, -0.6802765400695919, 0.44552601044477186, 0.10820787964125786, -1.584483680411645, 0.2007759414522207, -0.7101547556233192]
 बाट
[0.7488351202673913, 0.3645634610332536, 0.1937027124201285, -0.10361011958447905, 0.48222626651261347, 0.36795608937720814, -0.06307932558713457, -0.05626217864435294, -0.5245206209054951, 0.40256760017279525]
रूपमा
[0.06077674960453302, 0.2570556052636379, 0.3347552495487344, -0.10512580657948888, 0.10414134700640766, 0.19736087970834254, 0.09207914995816116, 0.19904934221006, 0.061402311347008, -0.11409541813280075]
बोर्डमा
[0.5200111891848155, -0.14947230042320633, 0.7351562111464331, -0.7542450932215059, 1.4477558941048831, -0.6235133303135835, -0.7781689512584442, -0.057886889872348815, 0.10625424653444066, 0.9777761194886687]
आउनु
[1.0596966006985387, 0.24909505933749815, 0.5181999691383957, -0.01983089009044503, -1.4106664226234644, -0.020542297788816014, -0.7822719255911348, 0.42914674116391344, -0.5753257725556651, -0.9141151600890186]
```

The word is like  
    `नोभेम्बर`  are data points and the numeric values are their vector representation. I would like to take those representation as co-ordinate and plot them so as to find the relations among them. What can be the possibilities to plot them.Any suggested tools are really appreciated.

Comment: Some potential solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6775352/636656

Comment: why does this have so many tags? Do you want a solution in any or all of these packages? Why not python, ruby, C or fortran?

Comment: i want solution from any of those. I feel comfortable working on those. solution from other domains are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

My GUI couldn't handle that font for the item names, but if I name them: a,b,cc,d,e,  you can use parallel coordinate plots to display multi-dimensional features:

```
require(MASS)  # an R package
parcoord(data.frame(a=a,b=b,cc=cc,d=d,e=e), col=1:5)
```

[image]

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, I think the OP meant it the other way around: 5 instances of 10-dimensions each (as in you need to transpose the matrix)

Comment: Could very well be. I can't tell from the description. I'm thankful to the questioner for bringing this up. I have already applied it to my research questions today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MATLAB solution.

First we read the data. Although MATLAB is capable of reading Unicode text, it has [some issues displaying it in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6872642/97160) (so I'm just replacing the labels with Point1/Point2, etc..)

```
%# read file lines
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'rt', 'native', 'UTF-8');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
C = C{1};

%# split into labels/data
labels = C(1:2:end);
data = cellfun(@str2num, C(2:2:end), 'UniformOutput',false);
data = cell2mat(data);

%# HACK: MATLAB has issues displaying unicode text
labels = num2str((1:size(data,1))', 'Point %d');
```

Next we can plot the data using [parallel coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942575/97160):

```
%# you might need to normalize the attributes
%#data = zscore(data);

plot(data');            %'# plot lines
set(gca, 'XTick',1:numDim, 'XGrid','on')
xlabel('Features'), ylabel('Feature value')
title('Parallel Coordinates')
legend(labels)          %# show legend of labels
```

[image: parallel coordinates]

If you have access to the Statistics Toolbox, you can [visualize multivariate data](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/mvplotdemo.html) using a number of techniques:

```
%# parallel coordinates (similar the above)
parallelcoords(data, 'Group',labels)

%# glyph plot (stars)
glyphplot(data, 'obslabels',labels, 'glyph','star')
```

[image: glyphplot_star]

```
%# glyph plot (Chernoff faces)
glyphplot(data, 'obslabels',labels, 'glyph','face')
```

[image: glyphplot_face]

```
%# Andrews curves
andrewsplot(data, 'Group',labels)
```

[image: andrewsplot]