# Plot result of multiple dimensions K means

Tags: r, dataframe, k-means

I have a question about Kmeans in R. I have a dataframe like the IRIS data that is available in R. I found a [website](http://www.wanderinformatiker.at/unipages/ParCoord/clustering_en.html) where they create a kmeans result that i like: [image]

My question is, I want to reproduce the figure with my own data (dataframe 100X4) but i can't find how to do that. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942508/implementation-of-parallel-coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parallel coordinates plot. You can use for example the `parcoord` function from `MASS` --

```
library(MASS)
iris$Species = as.numeric(iris$Species)
parcoord(iris, col=iris$Species)
```