# color the cluster output in r

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a set of cluster output. I want to show each cluster with unique color in parallel coordinate graph. I am using rggobi for parallel coordinate graph. I used this link
http://www.ggobi.org/docs/parallel-coordinates/

here is my code to load the data to ggobi

```
library(rggobi)
mydata <- read.table("E:/Thesis/Experiments/R/input.cvs",header = TRUE,sep = ",")
 g <- ggobi(mydata)
```

here is my output
[image: parallel coordinate]

I want to use different color to represent different clusters.

Comment: Please include reproducible code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use MASS:::parcoord():

```
require(MASS)
cols = c('red', 'green', 'blue')
parcoord(iris[ ,-5], col = cols[iris$Species])
```

Or with ggplot2:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
iris$ID <- 1:nrow(iris)
iris_m <- melt(iris, id.vars=c('Species', 'ID'))
ggplot(iris_m) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = variable, y = value, group = ID, color = Species))
```

[image]

Please note also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942508/implementation-of-parallel-coordinates) post!