# color discrete groups of parallel coordinate plot in GGally package

Tags: r, ggplot2, parallel-coordinates, ggally

To create a parallel coordinate plot I wanted to use `ggparcoord()` function in package `GGally`. The following codes show a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(3674)
k <- rep(1:3, each=30)
x <- k + rnorm(mean=10, sd=.2,n=90)
y <- -2*k + rnorm(mean=10, sd=.4,n=90)
z <- 3*k + rnorm(mean=10, sd=.6,n=90)

dat <- data.frame(group=factor(k),x,y,z)

library(GGally)
ggparcoord(dat,columns=1:4,groupColumn = 1)
```

[image]

Notice in the picture that the color for group was continuous even though I have the group variable as a factor. Is there any way I can display the plot with three discrete color instead?

I have looked at some other posts where they discuss various other ways of doing parallel coordinate plots in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942508/implementation-of-parallel-coordinates). But I really wanted to do this in `ggparcoord()` function of package `GGally`. I appreciate your time in thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was almost correct. I spotted that `columns=1:4` was not right in this case. You need to drop the column for `groupColumn` in `columns`

```
ggparcoord(dat,columns=2:4,groupColumn = 1)
```

[image]